# Can't get Jekyll to install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, jekyll

I am following this page:
https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages/

I am up to step 3 and I believe I did what they told me to but for some reason it won't go thru.

Gemfile syntax error on line 1: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting
end-of-input
source: 'https://rubygems.org'

Answer (score 1):

Try this Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'github-pages'
```